# Jssor scrollable Slide

Tags: jquery, jssor

I am developing a website, that uses the jssor slideshow plugin for a fullscreen slider. I got everything to work as intended except one major thing: For each slide I want to have multiple images that can be scrolled through by moving the mousewheel.

I already tried setting `overflow:scroll;` to the slide element, and that allowed me to scroll through the images. But as it is a fullscreen slider that gets scaled via css, the scrollbar gets scaled aswell. The result is, that if I adjust the viewport size, the scrollbar gets scaled to unusual sizes. And even further makes it impossible to scroll to the very bottom of the slide.

Any ideas how to solve this? Is there a better way to make each slide scrollable instead of adding `overflow:scroll;` to the slide element?